# Уменьшить объем веб-приложения asp.net mvc, используя только нужные пакеты?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Как вообще создается веб-приложение asp.net mvc без всяких пакетов типа Owin, Twitter и т.п.?
Создаю веб-приложение ASP.Net MVC и смотрю, размер проекта слишком большой = ~110-120 Мб. Это слишком большой размер файлов. Понятно, что нужно удалять пакеты. Но что именно нужно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что нужно во время создания проекта MVC щелкнуть на кнопку "Change Authentication" и выбрать "No Authentication".